# Vector space of step functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Considering $\mathcal{L}_{step}$ is the vector space of all step functions on $\mathbb{R}$, which of the following statements are true?
>
> (a) $\mathcal{L}_{step}$ is the linear span of all indicator functions ${\bf{1}}_{(a,b)}$ of bounded open intervals;
>
> (b) $\mathcal{L}_{step}$ is the linear span of all indicator functions ${\bf{1}}_{[a,b]}$ of bounded closed intervals;
>
> (c) $\mathcal{L}_{step}$ is the linear span of all indicator functions ${\bf{1}}_{(a,b]}$ of bounded left-half-open intervals.

I'm thinking (b) is true, as you can create any step function from linear combinations of ${\bf{1}}_{[a,b]}$. i.e. if you need ${\bf{1}}_{(a,b]}$ you can just do ${\bf{1}}_{[a,b]}-{\bf{1}}_{[a,a]}$.

For (a) I'm not entirely sure. If you needed ${\bf{1}}_{[a,b]}$ can you make that from a linear combination of open intervals? (Intuitively I'm thinking you can, but I'm not seeing how)

(c) I'm not sure on, but if I understood (a) better I'd probably work out (c) as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that linear combinations must have only a finite number of summands.

Comment: @vadim123 So this would imply (a) is not true, given how you could only make a bounded interval with an infinite linear combination (I think).

Comment: Similarly with (c) else how do you make $[0,1]$?

Comment: @vadim123 Yeah, you can't? Since to make it closed on the left you'd need an infinite sum of combinations.

Comment: What precisely is a step function? If you look at e.g. the Heaviside function, it's in none of these spans, since it has nonzero values at unbounded points. Do we assume they are finitely supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I take the following key definitions:

- *step functions* are $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which take the form of finite linear combinations of indicator functions on arbitrary intervals; but for this problem we additionally assume the functions also have bounded support
- only finite linear combinations are taken in the linear span (algebraic definition rather than analytic type thing)

Then the question reduces to: can you recreate $\mathbf 1_{(a,b)}, \mathbf 1_{(a,b]}, \mathbf 1_{[a,b]}$ for arbitrary $b\ge a$?

For (b), as you successfully argue, each of these is straightforward.

For (a), here's a hint: $(0,2)\setminus((0,1)\cup(1,2))=?$.

For (c), I'll leave you to have a think.