# Linear span of indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis

Fix $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. Denote by $\mathscr{L}_{\text{step}}$ the set of all step functions on $[a,b]$. Is it true that $\mathscr{L}_{\text{step}}$ is the linear span of all indicator functions $\boldsymbol{1}_{(c,d]}$ of bounded left-half-open intervals, restricted to $[a,b]$?

I think the answer is 'no', as there doesn't seem to be any way of getting e.g. a constant function on $[a,b]$ from a finite linear combination of $\boldsymbol{1}_{(c,d]}$ functions. But how to prove it? This problem is addressed already at [Can you create the indicator functions for closed and open intervals from indicator functions for half-open intervals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776810/can-you-create-the-indicator-functions-for-closed-and-open-intervals-from-indica) and [Vector space of step functions on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378774/vector-space-of-step-functions-on-mathbbr), but neither provides a proof, so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Your question should perhaps be: Let L be the step functions supported  on $(a,b]$. Is L generated by indicator functions on $(c,d]$ with $c,d$ arbitrary. The answer is no.

Comment: The question definitely has $[a,b]$, rather than $(a,b]$. Is the answer still no?

Comment: The answer is still no, but as mentioned by the answer below your argument does not work. A propoer argument goes through left-continuity.

Comment: Can you please specify the argument in more detail?

Comment: OK, but before that: Is this a homework assignment? If so I will be happy to give indications, but not a complete answer

Comment: It's not. If the answer is 'no', as I thought, then it resolves another question I was thinking about. After I couldn't come up with a proof myself, I posted it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $f$ defined on ${\Bbb R}$ is said to be left-continuous at $m$ iff
  $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow m^-} f(x) = f(m) .$$
Now, as you see quickly, any indicator function on a half-open interval of the form $(c,d]$ is left-continuous (just go through the possibilities). When restricted to $[a,b]$ such an indicator function is left-continuous at any point in $(a,b]$ (more precisely at any point in ${\Bbb R}\setminus \{a\}$).

Left-continuity is preserved by linear combinations, so any step function $f$  which is not left-continuous in $(a,b]$ (and there are plenty), can not be in the linear span.

This argument obviously also settles the question that you linked to.